# Is OpenID Connect dynamic registration possible with salesforce.com?

Tags: openid, openid-connect

My team is building a framework that developers will use to make their applications OpenID Connect Relying Parties. The first provider we'd like to support is Salesforce. SFDC has a page for users to register their app as a relying party, but we would like to do this programatically, using the [OpenID Connect Dynamic Registration](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html) process.

I've been unable to find SFDC's [registration endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ClientRegistration). Their [discovery endpoint](https://login.salesforce.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) does not return one. Is it possible to dynamically register an OpenID Connect relying party with salesforce.com? If so, what is the URL and where is it documented? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic registration is not supported by Salesforce's OpenID Connect implementation at this point in time; they restrict registration to clients operated by their customers/users like may of the big vendors, so they only offer client registration through the administration GUI after logging in the customer.